# What is the shortest way to write condition variable in rails view template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, dry, conditional-operator

I have to put something in my .erb template , which uses conditional operator.

In the code below you can see I am checking the conditional value and printing the same value if its not nil.

```
<%= (@variable.value.nil?) ? "-" : @variable.value %>
```

I guess there should be a more shorter way to do this. As it really looks ugly to write same things twice.

Comment: Are you using Rails? Do you want to check for `nil` only? What about empty values – like an empty string (`""`)?

Comment: Should `@variable.value` be allowed to be `false`?

Answer (score 5):

When you are using Ruby on Rails then you can use the [`presence`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence) helper method which returns `self` only when self is present:

```
<%= @variable.value.presence || "-" %>
```

Compared to your version `presence` also handles cases in which `@variable.value` returns an empty string.